# Linux script is unable to delete files via crontab, but it works manually

Tags: linux, bash, cron, rm

I have a simple script file to copy all files to a remote server and then delete them all. I could run this script by "user" manually, when i add into crontab (user), the first part, scp, works fine, but the rm part is always with failure. 
i wonder what i am missing or set up incorrectly, could somebody help me out with this ?

thanks in advance

#### /home/user/bin/test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

scp -v -r /var/spool/asterisk/monitor test@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/test/audio&&sudo rm -f /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/*
```

#### access permission of /var/spool/asterisk/monitor

```
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 532 Sep 06 11:14 monitor
```

#### crontab - user]

```
* */1 * * * bash /home/user/bin/test.sh
```

Comment: Does `sudo` require a password for that command? Or attempt to ask for one or anything? (Even just requiring a `tty` would be a problem for a command run under `sudo`.)

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will work if sudo does not require password ( and it is possible ) )

```
scp -v -r /var/spool/asterisk/monitor test@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/test/audio &&   ssh test@xx.xx.xx.xx "sudo rm -f /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/*"
```

Comment: If the files were on the remote system already why would `scp` be involved here in the first place?

Comment: i want to delete local files, not the files in the remote folder.

Comment: >> , but the rm part is always with failure.     >>                                                   ok, what is the error then ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `requiretty` is `off` in `/etc/sudoers`. It is normally `on` by default on Red Hat.